# remove only *some* fullstops from a csv file

Tags: bash, perl, sed, tr

If I have lines like the following:

```
1,987372,987372,C,T,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,1,D,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,1.293,12.23,0.989,0.973,D,.,.,.,.,0.253,0,4.08,0.917,1.048,1.000,1.000,12.998
1,987393,987393,C,T,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,1,D,.,.,.,.,.,.,0.152,1.980,16.09,0.999,0.982,D,-0.493,T,0.335,T,0.696,0,5.06,0.871,0.935,0.998,0.997,16.252
```

how can I replace all instances of `,.,` with `,?,`

I want to preserve actual decimal places in the numbers so I can't just do

```
sed 's/./?/g' file
```

however when doing:

```
sed 's/,.,/,?,/g' file
```

this only appears to work in some cases. i.e. there are still instances of `,.,` hanging around.

anyone have any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
sed ':a;s/,\.,/,?,/g;ta' file
```

With successive `,.,` strings, after a substitution succeeded, next character to be processed will be the following `.` that doesn't match the pattern, so with you need a second pass.

`:a` is a label for upcoming loop

`,\.,` will match dot between commas. Note that the dot must be escaped because `.` is for matching any character (`,a,` would match with `,.,`).

`g` is for general substitution

`ta` tests previous substitution and if it succeeded, loops to `:a` label for remaining substitutions.

Comment: thanks Kenavoz. This has worked. I suspected this was the case. if you don't mind, could you explain how each part works? I only really understand  `s/,\.,/,?,/g`. and why escape before the `.`?

Comment: IMO it's kinda clunky to take two passes when all that is needed is a proper regex pattern for it to work in one go

Comment: @Borodin Which sed regex would you suggest ?

Comment: @Kenavoz: I wouldn't suggest a sed regex

Comment: @Borodin It seems you don't have a proper regex to suggest but another approach using perl. Just make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed it is possible by running a loop as shown in above answer however problem is easily solved using `perl` command line with lookarounds:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=,)\.(?=,)/?/g' file

1,987372,987372,C,T,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,D,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1.293,12.23,0.989,0.973,D,?,?,?,?,0.253,0,4.08,0.917,1.048,1.000,1.000,12.998
1,987393,987393,C,T,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,D,?,?,?,?,?,?,0.152,1.980,16.09,0.999,0.982,D,-0.493,T,0.335,T,0.696,0,5.06,0.871,0.935,0.998,0.997,16.252
```

This command doesn't need a loop because instead of matching surrounding commas we're just asserting their position using a lookbehind and lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

All that's necessary is a single substitution

```
$ perl -pe 's/,\.(?=,)/,?/g' dots.csv
1,987372,987372,C,T,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,D,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1.293,12.23,0.989,0.973,D,?,?,?,?,0.253,0,4.08,0.917,1.048,1.000,1.000,12.998
1,987393,987393,C,T,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,D,?,?,?,?,?,?,0.152,1.980,16.09,0.999,0.982,D,-0.493,T,0.335,T,0.696,0,5.06,0.871,0.935,0.998,0.997,16.252
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an example using `sed` style regular expressions. I'll offer an alternative - parse the CSV, and then treat each thing as a 'field':

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#iterate input row by row
while ( <DATA> ) { 
   #remove linefeeds
   chomp;
   #split this row on ,
   my @row = split /,/;
   #iterate each field  
   foreach my $field ( @row ) {
       #replace this field with "?" if it's "."
       $field = "?" if $field eq ".";
   }
   #stick this row together again. 
   print join ",", @row,"\n";
}

__DATA__
1,987372,987372,C,T,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,1,D,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,1.293,12.23,0.989,0.973,D,.,.,.,.,0.253,0,4.08,0.917,1.048,1.000,1.000,12.998
1,987393,987393,C,T,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,1,D,.,.,.,.,.,.,0.152,1.980,16.09,0.999,0.982,D,-0.493,T,0.335,T,0.696,0,5.06,0.871,0.935,0.998,0.997,16.252
```

This is more verbose than it needs to be, to illustrate the concept. This could be reduced down to:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", map { $_ eq "." ? "?" : $_ } @F'
```

If your CSV also has quoting, then you can break out the `Text::CSV` module, which handles that neatly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need 2 passes since the trailing `,` found on a `,.,` match isn't available to match the leading `,` on the next `,.,`:

```
$ sed 's/,\.,/,?,/g; s/,\.,/,?,/g' file
1,987372,987372,C,T,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,D,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1.293,12.23,0.989,0.973,D,?,?,?,?,0.253,0,4.08,0.917,1.048,1.000,1.000,12.998
1,987393,987393,C,T,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,D,?,?,?,?,?,?,0.152,1.980,16.09,0.999,0.982,D,-0.493,T,0.335,T,0.696,0,5.06,0.871,0.935,0.998,0.997,16.252
```

The above will work in any sed on any OS.